# Is it safe to be at Union Station, Washington DC from 12AM to 2AM?

Tags: trains, washington-dc

My bus is scheduled to depart at 2.30AM. I'm planning to get there at 12AM by metro. Is it safe to stay in the Union station for mentioned hours?

Is it at least slightly crowded at that time?

Comment: Please define what is 'safe' for you. Not being a victim of a violent crime? Not being a crime victim (even if nonviolent)? Not seeing suspicious activity around (even if they don't interact with you)? Not being in an empty space?

Comment: All of that. Just wanted to know whether the place will be okay to spend during that time without a trouble.

Comment: The issue here is what is trouble for one person is not a problem for another one, which makes it hard to give a clear answer.

Comment: Can I spend that time duration uninjured or with no harm done. Is that time period id protected from or not exposed to danger or risk, not likely to be harmed? That's what I'm asking. If there are people like in day time, then at least I can escalate since there are people. But I'm asking about the time 12AM to 2AM where i think there won't be lot of people even to escalate during a danger.

Comment: Any place near Capital Hill is generally safe and patrolled, but I wouldn't go up North Capital Street.  It looks like this question is an opinion poll. Some say yes, some say no. Who's right? Close voting as opinion-based, sorry